# Managing forms through another controller and staying on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, stripe-payments

I am trying to get my head around how I can build stripe payment into my events controller of, but I am struggling to figue out how everything works without going to say '/registration/new' and keeping the user on the same page i.e. /tech.

Note - I am using mongoid not activerecord

Heres my code so far:

### Model

```
class Registration
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :address 
  field :email
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :postcode
  field :stripe_card_token
  field :stripe_customer_token

  def save_with_payment event
    if valid?
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
        amount: total_price(event),
        currency: "gbp",
        card: stripe_card_token,
        description: email
      })
      save
    end
  rescue
    false
  end

  def total_price attribute
    price = attribute.price
    price
  end
end
```

### Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @registration, :html => { :class => 'custom medium' },
      :method => :post, :url => registration_path do |f| %>
  <h2>Contact Information</h2>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :postcode %>
  <!-- Add stripe card details -->
  <h2>Payment Information</h2>
  <%= f.input :stripe_card_token, as: :hidden %>
  <div class="input card_number">
    <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="input card_cvc">
    <label for="card_code">Security code (CVC)</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_cvc %>
  </div>
  <div class="input card_dates">
    <label>Card expiration date</label>
    <%= select_month nil, { add_month_number: true }, { id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil,
          { add_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 15 },
          { id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Register" %>
<% end %>
```

### Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @event = Event.where(:slug => params[:slug]).first
    @registration = Registration.new
  end

  def payment
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
    if @registration.save_with_payment(@event)
      redirect_to event_path, :notice => "Thank you for registering"
    else
      redirect_to event_path, :notice => "We're sorry, something went wrong"
    end
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
Disrupt::Application.routes.draw do

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  root to: "pages#home"

  match '/home' => "pages#home"
  match '/:slug' => "events#show"

end
```

At present the page is redirecting to the home page and not going back to the events page to show the notice, I have only been working with rails for a few months so I am still learning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't specify the index action in EventsController. `def index end`. I think this helps. Or it might be more helpful if you provide routes.

Comment: I don't have an index page or controller. I have added routes like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenerio there could be 2 cases -:

1.When you want to redirect user to events index page as your event_path shows. Then you have wrong action declaration in controller. In `EventsController` add one more action for index

```
def index 
end
```

and make your Routes like this if you want to go to events index page -:

```
Disrupt::Application.routes.draw do

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config



  match '/home' => "pages#home"
  match '/:slug' => "events#show"
  match '/events' => "events#index"
  root to: "pages#home"

end
```

2.If you want to redirect page to events show page then you have to pass one `@event` instance variable in you `events_path(@event)` -:

```
     def payment
      @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
      if @registration.save_with_payment(@event)
        redirect_to event_path(@event), :notice => "Thank you for registering"
      else
        redirect_to event_path(@event), :notice => "We're sorry, something went wrong"
      end
     end
```

I think this helps you.